# AWS Amplify to talk to rest api in ec2 created in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I've just used AWS Amplify to create my react frontend and AppSync API which is nice. I have a spring batch project that I've deployed to ec2 using elastic beanstalk and codepipeline which works fine.

I can also call the REST endpoints on postman but the problem is how do I programmatically update the API endpoint URL in my frontend project given that I do terminate and re-create the elastic beanstalk environment on a daily basis?

Comment: Have you hardcoded the EB endpoint url in the front-end up? If yes, then could create a Route53 record for that. So your front-end would only have fixed Route53 url. The R53 url would point to EB. Whenever you re-create your EB env you could automatically update R53 record to point to the new EB url.

Comment: That sounds like a viable option. Could you please be more specific about the Route53 record? My rest api in ec2 is currently unreachable from the frontend as it's making a HTTP call instead of HTTPS. The aws docs say I need to create a custom domain but I just want to use my existing domain name from Elastic Beanstalk (i.e http://myrestapi.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

Comment: I will add an answer with extra info, as I can't fit them into comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

You sadly can't add ssl to `myrestapi.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`. The reason is that this is domain controlled by AWS. You can only request SSL certificates for domains that you [control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) (i.e. own):

> Before ACM issues a certificate, it validates that you **own or control** the domain names in your certificate request. You can use either email validation or DNS validation.

Thus if you want to have ssl for your EB, you need to have your **own domain**. You can get one from `Route53`:

- [Creating an Amazon Route 53 record that routes traffic to your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set)

If you are constantly **changing your EB**, its URL will be changing as well. Thus you would need to setup some automation procedure to update the record set in Route53 to new url. There are examples for that, though they would need to be adapted specifically to your use-case:

- [A Dynamic DNS system built with API Gateway, Lambda & Route 53.](https://github.com/awslabs/route53-dynamic-dns-with-lambda)
- [Building a Dynamic DNS for Route 53 using CloudWatch Events and Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-dynamic-dns-for-route-53-using-cloudwatch-events-and-lambda/)

Comment: thank you very much Marcin, I've now registered a new domain and followed your link to create an alias to point to ELB environment. Cheers!